# Javascript regex expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a username in Javascript where only the patterns below can pass:

1. ABC-DE-0001
2. XEG-SS-21626
3. FK1S-DAD-51345

Mine is currently using `^[A-Z]{3}[\- ]?[A-Z]{2}[\- ]?[0-9]{4}$`.

Are there any improvements to validate all above patterns in one string?

```
var v = document.getElementById('<%=txtCode.ClientID%>').value;
var patternForID = /^[A-Z]{3}[\- ]?[A-Z]{2}[\- ]?[0-9]{4}$/;
if (patternForID.test(v) == '') {
  sender.innerHTML = "Please enter Valid Remeasurement Code";
  args.IsValid = false;  // field is empty
}
```

Comment: Your third example won't pass.

Comment: The second example won't pass either.

Comment: Is white space a valid separator to replace the hyphen or is that just extra clutter in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression matches all three of your examples:

```
^([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z0-9]{4})-[A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{4,5}$
```

It's hard to tell exactly what your requirements are from those examples, but here's what the regex above matches.

`([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z0-9]{4})` - Either three capital letters or any mix of 4 characters from capital letters and numbers.

`[A-Z]{2,3}` - Two or three capital letters.

`[0-9]{4,5}` - Four or five digits.

I assumed that `-` was your only legal separator, so I made it a literal `-` in the regex.  If your separator really can be either a space or a `-`, change it back to `[- ]`.  Also, adding a `?` after the separator makes it optional, which doesn't seem to fit your examples.  Naturally, you need to put it back if the separators are optional.

See it work in [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%7C%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B4%7D%29-%5BA-Z%5D%7B2,3%7D-%5B0-9%5D%7B4,5%7D%24&input=ABC-DE-0001%0AXEG-SS-21626%0AFK1S-DAD-51345%0A) with your examples.